# cant get json data from url like www.exemple.com/json.php?apicall=cat

Tags: android, json

I am trying to get JSON data from a URL like

> www.exemple.com/json.php?apicall=cat

it works nice in the browser but it doesn't work in my android application.
here is my code :

```
    request = new JsonArrayRequest(JSON_URL, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

            JSONObject jsonObject = null;
            lstAnime.clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {


                try {
                    jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                    Anime anime = new Anime();
                    anime.setId(jsonObject.getInt("id"));
                    anime.setName(jsonObject.getString("name"));
                    anime.setDescription(jsonObject.getString("description"));

                    anime.setImage_url(jsonObject.getString("path"));
                    lstAnime.add(anime);


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }

            setuprecyclerview(lstAnime);
            mSwipRefresh.setRefreshing(false);


        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });


    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
    requestQueue.add(request);

}
```

I am using volley library.
can anyone help me, please?

Comment: please show me your json response if its possible or you cat check your link in postman or check your Status code are 200 or other?

Comment: its work perfect in postman and browser.

Comment: what is your status code e.g. 200 OK or anything else?

Comment: yes 200 OK this



    Status Code: 200 OK
    X-Firefox-Spdy: h2
    cf-ray: 44608e3de9a36956-CDG
    content-encoding: br
    content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
    date: Mon, 06 Aug 2018 09:42:49 GMT
    expect-ct: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
    server: cloudflare
    x-powered-by: PHP/7.0.31

Comment: OKay then you can change your this method and debug which error code you have to get :
@Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        if (error.networkResponse != null) {
                            int statusCode = error.networkResponse.statusCode;
                            NetworkResponse response = error.networkResponse;
                            Log.d("testerror", "" + statusCode + " " + response.data);
                        }
                    }

Comment: this is the log cat
08-06 12:30:06.038 4929-5061/? E/MotionRecognitionService: handleMessage: event 200 value : 1
08-06 12:30:11.666 4929-5061/? E/MotionRecognitionService: handleMessage: event 200 value : 1

Comment: one another try to put code in your jason method override getHeaders():
 @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() {
                Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                headers.put("User-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (TV; rv:44.0) Gecko/44.0 Firefox/44.0");
                return headers;
            }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177501/discussion-between-oualid-oukassou-and-saif).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 @Override
public void onResponse(String response) {
    try {
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);// you need to transform your response to object
        arrayObject = new JSONArray(obj);//put the object in the jsonarray
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayObject.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject parObj = (JSONObject) parArray.get(i);
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I hope this helps you, Greetings!

Comment: still same problem

Comment: Change the JSONRequest to StringRequest, it is easier to capture the data in a String and then pass it to list.

Comment: A pleasure to help you. (: